If I have linux on a partition of an SSD, can I erase it and merge the now empty partition with anotherone already containing data?
*I haven't installed Linux yet but wish to.
*I also appreciate that this isnt Ubuntu specific but I'm hoping that it isn't an issue. If it is then I appologise and understand.
I'm planning on installing Linux mint and have 2 drives - One with Windows and some personal files, and another (almost fully empty) with more personal files.
If I partition the second drive and install Linux there and later decide that I no longer want it, am I able to just remove it while keeping my other files?
I still don't fully understand drive partitions: are they recognised the same between operating systems?
Any help would be great, thanks.

Does this answer your question? GPARTED : Merge partition with unallocated partition

You certainly can do this, with (g)parted.
There are Live-ISOs, that can also be run from a USB stick, providing a GUI that will lead you through the process.
You will find all information you need by searching for parted [add/remove/merge/shrink] partition.
However, whatever you try to archive, do backup all you personal data, even when you not attempt anything.

Ok thank you very much. I still dont know much about what I'm doing,
Would it be better to just buy a separate SSD for Linux?

If you only want to play a bit with Linux and do not want to make a commitment yet, install the distibution of your choice on a USB stick and boot it from there.
You will usually have access to the other HDD/SSD. The stick might be a bit slower, but it will be enough for having a first impression.

Linux partitions have different filesystem than the windows ntfs, ntfs can be readable in linux but linux filesystems on windows are not easily readable, so plan accordingly. Also one advise during partitioning, donot try to move the front sectors in a partition cause this contains the boot loader, good luck.
